Alternate formal derivation of the Poisson Distribution
I've been trying to wrap my head around the Poisson distribution formally or in a manner that does not include any natural hand-wavey-ness that is so often used in introducing topics in probability/statistics. The traditional way that I learned the Poisson distribution involves splitting an interval $[0,1]$ into segments of length $1/n$ in which the probability of an event occurring in a segment is given by $\lambda/n$ (with $\lambda$ constant). Then the probability of $k$ events happening in the interval is $[0,1]$ is the probability that there are $k$ successes and $n-k$ failures, where each segment has an independent probability of zero or one events occurring. Lastly this is multiplied by $n\choose k$ to handle every permutation of successes and failures. The Poisson distribution follows from taking $n\rightarrow \infty$.
I was thinking about an alternative derivation for the formal definition of the Poisson distribution using the idea of a Poisson process. Intuitively, we can think of a special random variable $X$ (which we know as an exponential distribution, but is still a black box to us) that models the time it takes for an event to happen. A Poisson process is an object that represents the times in which $X$ will have an event. Formally we can represent a Poisson process $p$ as a sequence $\{t_i\}$ of times $t_i\in(0,1]$ such that $t_k<t_{k+1}$ (we do not require that the sequence be finite because there is a vanishingly small probability that the sequence $\{t_i\}$ asymptotically approach $1$). Let $P$ be the set of all Poisson processes. The difference between any two consecutive times $t_{i+1}-t_{i}$ is modeled by the variable $X$ where each difference is meant to be independent from each other.
Under this definition, we should be able to define a distribution over the set of possible Poisson processes $P$. Intuitively, the probability associated with a Poisson process is equal to the product of the probability of each consecutive time difference. For $p$ with a finite sequence this should be
$$Pr[P=p] = Pr[X=t_1]\cdot Pr[X=(t_2-t_1)]\cdot\cdots\cdot Pr[X=(t_{n}-t_{n-1})]\cdot Pr[X>1-t_n]$$
where the last probability requires that the "next" time generated by $X$ would be outside the interval we are measuring the frequency of $X$ (when $t_n=1$, any possible next time difference generated by $X$ will be outside the interval we measure and $Pr[X>(1-t_n)]=1$). In the case where $p$ is infinite, the product becomes infinite and we remove the last probability in the above equation.
However, this is not a valid definition because $X$ is a continuous random variable so $Pr[X=x]=0$ for any $x$. This is where I need help. How do you define a distribution over $P$ where each consecutive difference is independently modeled by $X$ (regardless of our knowledge of $X$)?
Once we have this distribution, we require that $X$ is such a random variable such that the expected value of the number of events in a single $p$, i.e. the length of $p$ is constant $\lambda$. I was thinking that once we have a distribution over $P$, we can utilize measure theory and Lebesgue integrals to find the probability of the subsets $A_k\subset P$ in which each $p\in A_k$ has length $k$. This also permits the subset $A_\infty\subset P$ of infinite Poisson processes.
The crux of my question however lies in trying to formally define a distribution over $P$ using the intuitive requirement that $X=t_{i+1}-t_i$ and are independent of each other.

I just skimmed this post very quickly. Yes, it is a rigorous fact that the PP counts event times when their differences are exponentially distributed.

@KurtG. Correct. I was more asking about a formal definition of a PP distribution predicated on the variable $X$ without any assumption on the behavior or $X$.

It’s common to back out the exponential distribution from Poisson. However the traditional definition first assumes that in any time segment of size $1/n$, there is a $\lambda/n$ probability an event occurs; Poisson process is in the limit. Exponentials are then derived from that. This is very different from assuming initial the existence of a continuous RV $X$ and defining a PP from independent time differences.

It’s an order of assumptions thing.

I don't get what you want to achieve. Based on independent exponentially distributed interarrival times the Poisson process is probably he simplest of all processes in terms of its construction. No Kolmogorov extension gymnastics like for Brownian motion. If you do not like that you have to argue against those innocent interarrival times. Why would one even bother to do that?

@KurtG. Just an exercise in reverse mathematics. In an example where we are given a RV $X$ how do we analyze a counting process dictated by $X$. For example, what if $X$ is not an exponential variable?
